# I'm getting a "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side" error for this code. I can't see whats wrong

Tags: javascript, function

[Broken Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GT8.png)

```js
const calcTip = function (bill) {
    if (bill >= 50 && bill =< 300) {
        return 0.15 * bill;
    } else {
        return 0.2 * bill;
    }
}
```

New to this, still early learning phase.

Just cannot see what is causing the error in the second line?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ... why You wrapping the function invocation in `console.log` (the function calls `console.log in it's body) , and make `<=` where's error ...

Comment: You can add code snippets using three consecutive back ticks(``` ```<code_here>``` ```).
Use it instead of image of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
"=<" with "<="
```

:)